# select with a where condition from nested subquery

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way do something like this (a conditional select from a nested subquery):

```
SELECT 
Id, 
Name WHERE Name LIKE '%Peter%' AS Peters, 
Name WHERE Name LIKE '%Mike%' AS Mikes 
FROM 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer) myset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
Id, 
case when Name LIKE '%Peter%' then Name else null end AS Peters, 
case when Name LIKE '%Mike%' then Name else null end AS Mikes 
FROM 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer) myset
```

Additionally, you could use the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id, Peters, Mikes 
from(
    select 
        case when Name like '%Peter%' then Name end as Peters,
        case when Name like '%Mike%' then Name end as Mikes
    from Customer)t
```